# Failing in Install Anaconda in C-shell

Tags: shell, anaconda

My shell is C shell, I cannot initial and activate conda environment, The following is what happens when I run conda activate:

CommandNotFoundError: Your shell has not been properly configured to use 'conda activate'.

Answer (score 0):

In your shell, execute the command:

`conda init bash`

I am assuming your shell name is bash. If not use it as per your shell.

```
Currently supported shells are:
  - bash
  - fish
  - tcsh
  - xonsh
  - zsh
  - powershell
```